# How can make custom array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Query:

```
SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`year` as service_year, t5.`month` as service_month, t6.id as country_id, t6.`country`, t7.`id` as mobile_operator_id, t7.`mobile_operator`, t1.`service_id`, t1.`gross_revenue_actual`, t1.`content_partner_share`
, t2.`service`
, t4.`collected_at`, t4.`id` as invoice_id
FROM `PaymentCollections` t1
JOIN `Services` t2 ON t1.`service_id` = t2.`id`
JOIN `PaymentCollectionInvoiceItems` t3 ON t3.`payment_collection_id` = t1.`id`
JOIN `PaymentCollectionInvoices` t4 ON t4.`id` = t3.`invoice_id`
JOIN `Months` t5 ON t5.`id` = t1.`month`
JOIN `Countries` t6 ON t6.`id` = t2.`country_id`
JOIN `MobileOperators` t7 ON t7.`id` = t2.`mobile_operator_id`
WHERE t1.`payment_collection_status_id` = 18
GROUP BY t1.`year`, t1.`month` ORDER BY t1.`year` DESC, t1.`month` ASC
```

When I run above typical query then found an array:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5132
        [service_year] => 2016
        [service_month] => April
        [country_id] => 116
        [country] => Kenya
        [mobile_operator_id] => 3
        [mobile_operator] => Airtel
        [service_id] => 16
        [gross_revenue_actual] => 11500.000000
        [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
        [service] => Christianity Portal
        [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 09:59:19
        [invoice_id] => 105
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4982
        [service_year] => 2016
        [service_month] => May
        [country_id] => 116
        [country] => Kenya
        [mobile_operator_id] => 3
        [mobile_operator] => Airtel
        [service_id] => 16
        [gross_revenue_actual] => 11500.000000
        [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
        [service] => Christianity Portal
        [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 10:02:21
        [invoice_id] => 106
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4732
        [service_year] => 2016
        [service_month] => June
        [country_id] => 116
        [country] => Kenya
        [mobile_operator_id] => 3
        [mobile_operator] => Airtel
        [service_id] => 16
        [gross_revenue_actual] => 11000.000000
        [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
        [service] => Christianity Portal
        [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 13:13:42
        [invoice_id] => 114
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5522
        [service_year] => 2015
        [service_month] => December
        [country_id] => 51
        [country] => Congo(Republic of)
        [mobile_operator_id] => 31
        [mobile_operator] => MTN
        [service_id] => 56
        [gross_revenue_actual] => 11500.000000
        [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
        [service] => Music On Demand
        [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 11:26:09
        [invoice_id] => 101
    )
```

By using above array, If `service_year`, `country`, `mobile_operator`, `service` are same but month are different then I want to create new array like below

```
$finalarray = {
0 = {
[id] => 4732,
[service_year] => 2016,
[service] => Christianity Portal,
[country] => Kenya,
[mobile_operator] => Airtel,
array{
array[April] {
[gross_revenue_actual] => 11500.000000
[content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
[collected_at] => 2016-06-24 10:02:21
},
array[May] {
    [gross_revenue_actual] => 11000.000000
    [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
    [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 13:13:42
    },
    array[June] {
        [gross_revenue_actual] => 11000.000000
        [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
        [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 13:13:42
        },
    }
}
1 = {
    [id] => 5522
    [service_year] => 2015
    [service_month] => December
    [country_id] => 51
    [country] => Congo(Republic of)
    [mobile_operator_id] => 31
    [mobile_operator] => MTN
    [service_id] => 56
    [gross_revenue_actual] => 11500.000000
    [content_partner_share] => 1000.000000
    [service] => Music On Demand
    [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 11:26:09
    [invoice_id] => 101
}
```

}

How can I do this when I have used Laravel 5 framework? Is it possible to modify my query to get such type of array?

I appreciate all hints and responses. Thanks ahead.

Comment: The question seems to be about writing a SQL query. So, I would prefer you to first ask this question in SQL community. As far as I know, you need to use GROUP BY clause in the SQL query to group the months, years, service or whatever you would like. Only based on the query result, you will need to decide that if you want to implement the query in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, here I have add query by edit my question.

Comment: You need to remove the Stdclass object from the returned array i guess?

Comment: what happen by removing Stdclass ?

Comment: i was asking that whether you need output as an array without stdclass object

Comment: yes without stdclass object

Answer (score 3):

you can parse the array in php in the following way,

**INPUT :-**

```
$result = array('0' =>
        array(
            'id' => 5132,
            'service_year' => 2016,
            'service_month' => 'April',
            'country_id' => 116,
            'country' => 'Kenya',
            'mobile_operator_id' => 3,
            'mobile_operator' => 'Airtel',
            'service_id' => 16,
            'gross_revenue_actual' => 11500.000000,
            'content_partner_share' => 1000.000000,
            'service' => 'Christianity Portal',
            'collected_at' => '2016-06-24 09:59:19',
            'invoice_id' => 105
        ),
        '1' =>
        array(
            'id' => 4982,
            'service_year' => 2016,
            'service_month' => 'May',
            'country_id' => 116,
            'country' => 'Kenya',
            'mobile_operator_id' => 3,
            'mobile_operator' => 'Airtel',
            'service_id' => 16,
            'gross_revenue_actual' => 11500.000000,
            'content_partner_share' => 1000.000000,
            'service' => 'Christianity Portal',
            'collected_at' => '2016-06-24 10:02:21',
            'invoice_id' => 106
        ),
        '2' =>
        array(
            'id' => 4732,
            'service_year' => 2016,
            'service_month' => 'June',
            'country_id' => 116,
            'country' => 'Kenya',
            'mobile_operator_id' => 3,
            'mobile_operator' => 'Airtel',
            'service_id' => 16,
            'gross_revenue_actual' => 11000.000000,
            'content_partner_share' => 1000.000000,
            'service' => 'Christianity Portal',
            'collected_at' => '2016-06-24 13:13:42',
            'invoice_id' => 114,
        ),
        '3' =>
        array(
            'id' => 5522,
            'service_year' => 2015,
            'service_month' => 'December',
            'country_id' => 51,
            'country' => 'Congo(Republic of)',
            'mobile_operator_id' => 31,
            'mobile_operator' => 'MTN',
            'service_id' => 56,
            'gross_revenue_actual' => 11500.000000,
            'content_partner_share' => 1000.000000,
            'service' => 'Music On Demand',
            'collected_at' => '2016-06-24 11:26:09',
            'invoice_id' => 101,
            ));
```

This is the PHP code u need to use to parse the above array to get the desired result.

```
<?php

$arraycheck = array();
$finalArray = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach ($result as $key => $values) {
    $flag = 0;
    $id = 0;
    $month = 0;
    foreach ($arraycheck as $k => $v) {
        if ($v['service_year'] == $values['service_year'] &&
                $v['country'] == $values['country'] &&
                $v['mobile_operator'] == $values['mobile_operator'] &&
                $v['service'] == $values['service']) {
            $flag = 1;
            $id = $k;
            $month = $v['service_month'];
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($flag == 0) {
        $arraycheck[$values['id']]['service_year'] = $values['service_year'];
        $arraycheck[$values['id']]['country'] = $values['country'];
        $arraycheck[$values['id']]['mobile_operator'] = $values['mobile_operator'];
        $arraycheck[$values['id']]['service'] = $values['service'];
        $arraycheck[$values['id']]['service_month'] = $values['service_month'];
        $finalArray[$values['id']] = $values;
    }
    if ($flag == 1 && !empty($id)) {
        $finalArray[$id][$month]['gross_revenue_actual'] = $finalArray[$id]['gross_revenue_actual'];
        $finalArray[$id][$month]['content_partner_share'] = $finalArray[$id]['content_partner_share'];
        $finalArray[$id][$month]['collected_at'] = $finalArray[$id]['collected_at'];
        $finalArray[$id][$values['service_month']]['gross_revenue_actual'] = $values['gross_revenue_actual'];
        $finalArray[$id][$values['service_month']]['content_partner_share'] = $values['content_partner_share'];
        $finalArray[$id][$values['service_month']]['collected_at'] = $values['collected_at'];
        unset($finalArray[$id]['gross_revenue_actual']);
        unset($finalArray[$id]['content_partner_share']);
        unset($finalArray[$id]['collected_at']);
        unset($finalArray[$id]['service_month']);
    }
    $counter++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
die;
?>
```

**OUTPUT :-**
output will be like this

```
Array
(
    [5132] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5132
            [service_year] => 2016
            [country_id] => 116
            [country] => Kenya
            [mobile_operator_id] => 3
            [mobile_operator] => Airtel
            [service_id] => 16
            [service] => Christianity Portal
            [invoice_id] => 105
            [April] => Array
                (
                    [gross_revenue_actual] => 
                    [content_partner_share] => 
                    [collected_at] => 
                )

            [May] => Array
                (
                    [gross_revenue_actual] => 11500
                    [content_partner_share] => 1000
                    [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 10:02:21
                )

            [June] => Array
                (
                    [gross_revenue_actual] => 11000
                    [content_partner_share] => 1000
                    [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 13:13:42
                )

        )

    [5522] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5522
            [service_year] => 2015
            [service_month] => December
            [country_id] => 51
            [country] => Congo(Republic of)
            [mobile_operator_id] => 31
            [mobile_operator] => MTN
            [service_id] => 56
            [gross_revenue_actual] => 11500
            [content_partner_share] => 1000
            [service] => Music On Demand
            [collected_at] => 2016-06-24 11:26:09
            [invoice_id] => 101
        )

)
```

I hope this will help you out